# eBuildfire: IOS issue for buildfire.navigation.openWindow parameter encoded

Tags: ios, encode, buildfire

Buildfire suppor team, I'm trying to open up a new link using buildfire.navigation.openWindow and I noticed an issue on IOS with the URL parameters, as the = (equal sign) gets URL encoded. Please see my example below and the attached screenshot.

https://example.com/something?id=1654161096657Felix
is transformed to
https://example.com/something?id%3D1654161096657Felix

[app code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWTyf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Example URL works fine:

```
buildfire.navigation.openWindow("https://example.com/something?id=1654161096657Felix", "_system")
```

And when inspecting the new window on device I'm getting this:

[image]

I would check the server (the real URL) you are using and see if it is redirecting the url to something else.